# Multiple OR statements in Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule, required-field, required

Im trying to figure out a Validation Rule
IF Picklist Value is "Yes", then 4 fields must be filled out AND at least 1 of 2 Solution Partner fields must be Filled out.
I can figure out how to require all fields, but Im getting stuck on how to add additionally at least 1 of 2 Solution Partner fields have to have values.

AND(
$RecordType.Id = "0125p000000eVI2",
ISPICKVAL( Picklist_Field,"Yes")

&&
OR(
ISBLANK(Main_Contact__c),
ISBLANK(Services__c),
ISBLANK (Contact_1__c),
ISBLANK(Decision_Maker__c)
)

&&

OR(
ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner1__c )
||
ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner2__c))

(this last Part is where I get an issue) if set up like this, Im able to save without either of the Solutions Partners

Answer (score 1):

Either use an `OR` function or `||` operator, correct syntax for both would be:

1. `OR(Condition1, Condition2)`
2. `Condition1 || Condition2`

Whereas you have written it as `OR(Condition1 || Condition2)`, that is not valid.

Indenting formulas can be extremely helpful in finding some trivial issues with syntax. This is an example of formula with `AND`/`OR` functions to improve readability-

```
AND(
    $RecordType.Id = "0125p000000eVI2", 
    ISPICKVAL( Picklist_Field,"Yes"),
    OR( 
        ISBLANK(Main_Contact__c), 
        ISBLANK(Services__c), 
        ISBLANK (Contact_1__c), 
        ISBLANK(Decision_Maker__c) 
    ),
    OR( 
        ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner1__c),
        ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner2__c)
    )
)
```

Note: I may have made a mistake in converting operator or in conditions, please check.

---

Edit: Seems you need a [XOR condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), replace the OR condition with below:

```
(ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner1__c) != ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner2__c))
```

Comment: But how do I ensure that only 1 of 2 Solutions Partners in the 2nd OR condition is required? at the moment with your formula it requires both

Comment: You perhaps need a [XOR condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), try replacing that OR condition with `(ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner1__c) != ISBLANK(Solutions_Partner2__c))`, that is equivalent or a XOR gate.